# Demodulation and RFID Readers

Tags: networking, rfid

I was wondering if anyone had an inclination of demodulation and packets regarding RFID chips, sensors, and tags.

When working with RF signals, and using a reader the device is capable of collecting any information in regarding the chip, sensor, tag within a specific amount of range.

Using a frequency full analyzer spectrum analyzer, and knowing the channel will grant me access to the tags, and information.

I was in a debate with someone and they told me I need a demodulator to intercept the packets.

I don't believe that I need that because the software would automatically connect and is capable to access the terminal and read/write the data from my location with the proper software.

am I right or wrong, I cannot find out any of that information.

Comment: It isnt clear what you'd use to read the RFID data. The spectrum analyzer can tell you the frequency distribution of a stable signal. It cannot decode the information contained in a transmission. What is your proposed setup ? Also, consider moving this to the electronics stack exchange since this is more focused on RF signal than IoT.

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't quite clear. Are you considering using a reader to read data from the chip, or using a spectrum analyser while a reader (you don't control) is reading data, or...? Also, even though I'm not sure this makes a difference here, what kind of RFID chips are you talking about (125 kHz, 13.56 MHz...), active or passive, and for 13.56 MHz chips (NFC, EMV...) what data do you want to read (some of it may be protected)?

Comment: Not sure why this was migrated here since the question is very much unclear and full of misconceptions. What exactly is a "reader"? RFID specifically has several different standards, NFC, Mifare classic and so on. Depending on which one you refer to, that standard specifies which frequency band that's used and how it is accessed etc. "Using a frequency full analyzer spectrum analyzer, and knowing the channel will grant me access to the tags, and information" No, a spectrum analyzer measures RF energy at given frequencies. It doesn't know jack about protocols.

Comment: "they told me I need a demodulator to intercept the packets" What's a "demodulator"? The technical meaning of that would rather mean something that translates the radio modulation (ASK - Amplitude Shift Keying - in case of NFC I believe) into some more convenient voltage modulated signal used by electronic boards. This too has nothing to do with protocols and packages.